# Android studio copying DB file to internal storage not wroking

Tags: android

I tried to retype see whether any typing error there but it still not working.
It does not even prompt me that I have any errors

I am thinking that is it my internal storage path file given wrongly?

This is where the internal storage file that i wanted to copy to!
[image: Path file]

This is how i called my method at onclick function:

```
 else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnBackup)){
        exportDatabase("stock.db");

    }
}
```

This is the method for exporting database:

```
 public void exportDatabase(String databaseName) {
    try {
        File sd = getFilesDir();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
            String backupDBPath = "//MyDb";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Backup Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method work perfect.

```
 public void exportDB(Context mContext) {
    try {
        File sd = mContext.getExternalFilesDir("/database/");
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + PACKAGE_NAME + "//databases//" + DATABASE_NAME;
            String backupDBPath = DATABASE_NAME;
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```